# Tx-Variable does not increment in modSecure

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-security

I use Apache2.4 and mod_security 2.

```
SecRuleEngine On
SecRule REQUEST_METHOD "@streq put" "id:12345,phase:1,pass,log,t:lowercase,chain,logdata:'TX:PUT_COUNT=%{tx.put_count}'"
SecRule REQUEST_URI "@contains /session/" "t:lowercase,log,setvar:tx.put_count=+1"
```

So [according to the docs](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual-(v2.x)#setvar), "setvar:tx.put_count=+1" should increase tx.put_count by one each request matching those criteria. But regardless how many i fire it stays at 1 as the log prove: `[data "TX:PUT_COUNT=1"]`.

What am I doing wrong? My setup look very similar to the example in the docs.